# How can I call an assembly file that contains a simple function from a C program function?

Tags: c, security, assembly, x86, 64-bit

I want to write a simple C program example that calls a file in .asm format and executes his code.
PSEUDO-CODE  ;)

```
    call(functionwithasmcode.asm);
```

Comment: You don't call a *file*, you call a *function*. And it will definitely have to be assembled before you can call it.

Comment: so is a kinda weird no sense question?

Comment: Assemby files get assembled into object files pretty much as C files do. Then they are linked to produce executable.

Comment: You want to compile the asm file at runtime, when you call that function?

Comment: Well, it's awfully broad. You get into questions of how to compile, assemble, and link, as well as calling conventions -- parameter passing, return values, etc.

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: It should be easy to find tutorials or examples of programs where C code calls a function defined in assembly in a separate file.  Just make sure you find one that's for your specific OS, compiler/assembler, and architecture (64-bit x86, not 32 bit).

Comment: Thanks I'll be working in this a few days, or weeks who knows...I'll let you know my results and maybe I can auto answer this question :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can::

`call("functionwithasmcode.asm");`

This function will have to:

1. Invoke the assembler and linker - create the dynamic link library.
2. Depending on the system you need to load this library (for example in Linux by calling the `dlopen` function, in Windows `LoadLibrary`).
3. Find your function in the library, assign to function pointer (it is also OS dependant for example in Linux `dlsym`, windows `GetProcAddress`)
4. call the function using the function pointer from the point 3.

Comment: Thank you 0, I'll study a bit more and let you know, because I can't answer this with knowledge yet, TY.

Comment: While this may answer what the question literally asked, it's almost certainly not what the asker really wants.  There are very few cases where it would make sense to assemble and link source code at runtime.

Comment: @NateEldredge I have answered the question asked. It is the correct answer. In your opinion the age correct answer should be DV-ted because you think that the OP had something else in mind. In comments, he did not say anything more than in the question.